# Reference AES-NI assembler code for AES-128-GCM?

Tags: aes, reference-request, implementation, gcm

I want to implement AES-128-GCM in assembler using Intel AES-NI instructions. I have found reference code in the [Intel AES-NI Whitepaper](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/doc/white-paper/advanced-encryption-standard-new-instructions-set-paper.pdf) but I don't see code for the GCM mode there (or indeed any use of the PCLMULQDQ instruction). Do I miss something in this document? Or could somebody point me to another similarly clean and simple implementation in assembler with AES-NI instructions that uses GCM mode?

I am hopeful that the implementation will be pretty straightforward given a good reference implementation and also good reference benchmarks for cycles per byte. The main reason I am reimplementing this is as an exercise in using an unusual assembler (DynASM).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a code request or asking for programming help.

Comment: [Maybe this will help you](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/software-support/enabling-high-performance-gcm.pdf).

Comment: What is your question? This site is not a discussion forum. For that I would recommend [sci.crypt](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sci.crypt). This site is for specific questions. So far all I see in your question is "did I miss something in a document" and "can you point me to some code that does what I want". Definitely not the types of questions we want on this site. I suggest you take the [site tour](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: I think this is a good question given that Intel has published this code and it is very difficult to find. I can't find a direct link to the Intel reference implementation, but I did find a copy of the Intel reference implementation at: https://secure.yikes.com/~bear/aesni-gcm.tar.gz